# VB.net ListBox Background Image

Tags: vb.net, image, background, listbox

How can I add a background image to a listbox? 
I'm using the NET Component listbox and the help of this post:
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?416784-2005-ListBox-Background-Image

I added the class to my project and a listbox1 on my form and declared it as

```
Public Class Form1
  Friend WithEvents ListBox1 As New MyListBox
  ...
```

And I get the error:
'ListBox1' is ambiguous because multiple kinds of members with this name exist in class 'Form1'.

What is wrong? Or is there another way to get a background image to my listbox?

Comment: Pick another name, ListBox1 is already used by the designer.  Consider that you actually meant to *replace* the ListBox that you put on your form.  We can't guess if that is what you intended.

Comment: Sorry but who is the designer? So just that you know what my plans are. I have a listbox (and the name is plain listbox1) on my form (form1). With my code I have a drag&drop feature so I can drag a file on the listbox. My goal is to add a background image to the listbox like in this picture. https://cdn.css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/drag-drop-upload-1.gif